# undefined method `even?' for nil:NilClass using injection

Tags: ruby, inject

I'm new to Ruby, and I'm having a hard time figuring out this error.

When I do:

```
ary = [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144]

ary.inject {|mem, i| mem + i if mem.even? && i.even? }
```

This error comes out:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `even?' for nil:NilClass)
```

I want to count only the pair(even) numbers.

Comment: You want to add only even numbers?

Comment: This can also be done with `array.select(&:even).reduce(:+)`

Comment: @steenslag I'd overlooked that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4):

To quickly review what `#inject` does when you pass it a block: the first iteration it passes the first element of your array (0) in the first block parameter, `mem`. It 'accumulates' the result from there by always passing the block the result *returned by the block last time*.

When you look at your block:

```rb
ary.inject { |mem, i| mem + i if mem.even? && i.even? }
```

You are returning `mem + i` when the condition is met. But, you are implicitly returning `nil` when the condition isn't met. Thus on the next iteration, `mem` is `nil` and you get your error. You probably want a ternary operator instead:

```rb
ary.inject { |mem, i| i.even? ? mem + i : mem }
```

Comment: You only need `i.even?` because `mem` will always be even.

Comment: @Stefan `ary.inject(0) { |mem, i| i.even? ? mem + i : mem }` to take care of an odd first element.
.